# Exception in custom Azure User Flows

Tags: azure, exception, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to custmoize the *User Flows (Policies)* by changing the *Page layout*. I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-user-flow#custom-html-and-css-overview) example, first putting [my html](https://emab2cblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/root/customize-ui.html) file on a public folder on my webspace, then also setting up the Blob Storare and CORS (Tested with [test-cors.org](https://www.test-cors.org/#?client_method=GET&client_credentials=false&server_url=https%3A%2F%2Femab2cblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net%2Froot%2Fcustomize-ui.html&server_enable=true&server_status=200&server_credentials=false&server_tabs=remote)).
In both cases, once I set the *Custom page URI*, when I *Run user flow* I get the following exception:

```
ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: MicrosoftIdentityError
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.TempDataDictionary.Add(string key, object value)
Microsoft.Identity.Web.TempDataLoginErrorAccessor.SetMessage(HttpContext context, string message)
Microsoft.Identity.Web.AzureADB2COpenIDConnectEventHandlers.OnRemoteFailure(RemoteFailureContext context)
Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthenticationBuilderExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass5_2+<<AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppInternal>b__5>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions>.HandleRequestAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

If I load it through my DemoApp I get the following error:

```
Message contains error: 'server_error', error_description: 'AADB2C90047: The resource 'https://emab2cblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/root/customize-ui.html' contains script errors preventing it from being loaded. Correlation ID: ba1a35d8-4727-4a2a-b06e-30a5ca7a9ea1 Timestamp: 2021-03-15 13:49:30Z ', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.
```

Don't find any help on the web.

Edit:
This are the Azure CORS settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. When I set up the CORS settings i did not read `Use all lowercase letters when entering your tenant name` of the [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-user-flow#3-configure-cors). If uppercase letters are used, this exception is thrown. Switching to lowercase was the key!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the correct `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header coming back when I make a request to your HTML.

Add `https://your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com` to the Allowed Origins on the storage account.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-user-flow#3-configure-cors

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it required? In all documentations I read that a wildcard * is enough. In the settings I have already added the origin. I'll update the question with a screenshot.

Comment: It says “ For Allowed Methods, select both GET and OPTIONS.” You only selected GET.

Comment: As far as I remember, GET calls do not require a OPTIONS preflight. However, I did some tests with OPTIONS and PUT (read on some guids) selected as well, don't work either. 
In the tutorial there is written to test it with test-cors.org, and indeed it works. So I think the CORS settings are not the problem.